# Comparing Lists and Dictionaries correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to compare a list with a dictionary's value, then print out the comparison differently to the rest.

I'm taking a list in this format:

```
list_1 = ['hostname ipaddress', 'hostname ipaddress']
```

I am then splitting it into a dictionary:

```
new_dict = {'hostname': 'ipaddress', etc}
```

I am then taking another list of 'items of interest':

```
list_interest = ['hostname', 'hostname']
```

to compare to the dictionary key value. If there is a match I want to print the matched item with special formatting, if there is no match just print the item with normal formatting.

Currently I am just trying to get `print 'yes'` and `print item` to make sure the logic works. But as you can see my thought process isn't working. I would imagine there is a better way to handle this problem? I understand why I'm getting duplicates, I'm just not sure how else to handle it.

**Test Code**

```
new_dict = dict((x.split(' ') for x in list_1))
for item in new_dict:
    for interest in list_interest:
        if new_dict.has_key(interest):
            print "yes" 
        else:
            print "\t", item
```

**Code output**

```
hostname1
hostname1
hostname1
yes
hostname2
hostname2
etc
```

**Working Code After** after taking on board Martijn Pieters initial example.

```
new_dict = dict((x.split(' ') for x in list_1))
    for item in new_dict:
        if item in interest:
            print "yes" 
        else:
            print "\t", item, new_dict[item]
```

Comment: What are you trying to check? Are you trying to check if each key in dictionary is in the interest list? or if each item in interest list is in dictionary?

Comment: what output are you expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your loops and testing item in the list while looping over the dictionary at the same time.

Just test if the key is in the list:

```
new_dict = dict((x.split(' ') for x in list_1))
for item in new_dict:
    if item in list_interest:
        print "yes" 
    else:
        print "\t", item
```

The membership test there (`item in list_interest`) will loop over the list to see if there is a value in there that is equal to it. That's not all that efficient, you could instead use a *set* here for O(1) constant time testing:

```
new_dict = dict((x.split(' ') for x in list_1))
set_interest = set(list_interest)
for item in new_dict:
    if item in set_interest:
        print "yes"
    else:
        print "\t", item
```

Demo:

```
>>> list_1 = ['hostname1 ipaddress1', 'hostname2 ipaddress2', 'hostname3 ipaddress3']
>>> list_interest = ['hostname1', 'hostname3']
>>> new_dict = dict((x.split(' ') for x in list_1))
>>> set_interest = set(list_interest)
>>> for item in new_dict:
...     if item in set_interest:
...         print "yes" 
...     else:
...         print "\t", item
... 
yes
    hostname2
yes
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That looks much closer to the goal than i was getting, but I would want to print the key and its value in both the if and else but just print them differently. How would I print both the key and value?

Comment: @iNoob: just loop over items then; `for hostname, ipaddress in new_dict.items():` and use `if hostname in set_interest:`. Now you have both the hostname and the associated IP address to print.

Comment: I worked it out after using your first example without the set. I will update working code in question. Thank you again.

Comment: @iNoob: sure, you can also look up the value by the key, but if you need almost all the values *anyway* you may as well use a loop over `dict.items()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking each `key` value with every value in the `list_interest`.

Suppose if this is your `dict` after splitting..

```
new_dict = {'hostname1': 'ip1', 'hostname2': 'ip2', 'hostname3': 'ip3'}
```

and your `list_interest` is ..

```
list_interest = ['hostname1', 'hostname4']
```

Your logic is doing this...(I've just escaped `if condition` to help you understand whats happening inside the loop)

```
for item in new_dict:
    for interest in list_interest:
        print interest, item
```

Output:

```
hostname1 hostname1
hostname4 hostname1
hostname1 hostname2
hostname4 hostname2
hostname1 hostname3
hostname4 hostname3
```

So, there is no need to iterate over `list_interest`, you can simply `iterate` over `new_dict` and check the value is present in the `list_interest` or not.

```
for item in new_dict:
    if item in list_interest:
        print 'yes'
    else:
        print item
```

This will give you the exact result you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_name = {1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3'}
list_name = ['1', '2', '4']
dict_name_values = list(dict_name.itervalues())
diff = list(set(dict_name_values).difference(set(list_name)))
# or
diff = list(set(list_name).difference(set(dict_name_values)))
```

You need to make sure in which sens you want the difference because the difference are establish for only one of the two set at a time.

Here the doc : https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference